# Is there concrete example of finite extension which is not normal?

Tags: field-theory, extension-field, splitting-field

I'm confusing about finite extension and normal extension. $E/F$be a finite extension. Then $E=F (a_{1},a_{2},a_{3},....,a_{n})$ and each $a_{i}$ is algebraic over $F$
Then there exist $f_{i}(x) $ in $F [x] $ which has $a_{i} $ as a root. Then I think $E$ is splitting field of product of all $f_{i}(x) $s. If it is right, there is no difference between finite extension and normal extension. Is there concret example of finite extension which is not normal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your reasoning doesn't make sense. The roots certainly lie in the splitting field, but why should you the splitting field be the same as the original? $\def\qq{\mathbb{Q}}$$\qq(\sqrt[3]{2}) / \qq$ is certainly a finite extension but not normal since it does not have the non-real roots of $x \mapsto x^3-2$.

Comment: Hmm, then how can I prove that given finite extension is not normal? Just check minimal polynomials of $a_{i}$s. May I know some related theorem?

Comment: @user277793: Sorry I typed wrongly. Edited my answer. But I don't know what you mean. It's not so simple. In the example I gave we use an ad-hoc method (namely our knowledge that the rationals can be embedded in the reals which contain the extension but not the other roots since if the other roots are there then a primitive cube root of unity is also, but this is non-real and hence is not contained in the extension in question.

Comment: Now I can understand difference of normal and finte ext. a little. But I leaned that F(a)=F (b)=F[x]/(p (x)) if p is irreducible and a, b are roots of p. Then isn't it true F (a) containing all roots of p??

Comment: @user277793: If you look at that construction carefully it does not do what you think it does. All you can prove is that in the quotient ring (which turns out to be a field), there is **a** root of $p$, not that there are all.

Comment: Thank you for correcting my misunderstanding. Then you mean normal extension is a special case of finite extension that contains all roots of minimal polynomial of $a $ whenever a is in such extension?

Comment: @user277793: Right. That property makes normal extensions very special. Any finite extension is contained in the splitting field of the product of minimal polynomials, which is a normal extension called the normal closure of the original finite extension, since it's the smallest containing normal extension. Also, how a field extension behaves under homomorphisms of a larger normal extension that fix the base field depend on whether it was normal or not. If it was normal, then it doesn't move (as a whole field). If it was not normal, then it gets moved by some homomorphisms.

Comment: You are genius I got it. Thank you so much!:)

Comment: @user277793: I'm hardly an expert. Anyway you can mark any answer to your question as accepted if you are fully satisfied with it, or you can wait for more comprehensive answers. Actually this question probably came up many times on this site before haha..